# This code for a chrome extension is not working, and I have no Idea

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, roblox

I am working on this small chrome extension for the Roblox web page, and for some reason, it doesn't want to work properly at all.

the error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'background' of undefined
at extension_update (themeManager.js:7)
at themeManager.js:14
```

and this is the code:

```
var colorOnePath = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-fixed-top rbx-header");
var colorTwoPath = [document.getElementsByTagName("body"), document.getElementsByClassName("content")];    

var color = ["#008919", "#000000"];

function extension_update() {
    colorOnePath.style.background = color[0];
    colorTwoPath[0].style.background = color[1];
    colorTwoPath[1].style.background = color[1];

    setTimeout(1000, extension_update)
};

extension_update()
```

I have no idea why the code is set up like this, but anyway, is there a problem anywhere? I couldn't find where to fix. thx!

Comment: note - `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]` === `document.body`

Answer (score 1):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) will always return an array-like collection of elements-- even if there is only one.  So in your code, instead of setting the `style.background` property on the first element in the collection, you're attempting to set it on the *collect itself* -- as the collection has no `style` property, you get the error you are seeing.  Try changing your code to this:

```
var colorOnePath = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-fixed-top rbx-header")[0];
var colorTwoPath = [document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0], document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0]];    

var color = ["#008919", "#000000"];

function extension_update() {
    colorOnePath.style.background = color[0];
    colorTwoPath[0].style.background = color[1];
    colorTwoPath[1].style.background = color[1];

    setTimeout(1000, extension_update);
}

extension_update();
```

(I also took the liberty of adding semi-colons where they were missing and removing them where they were unnecessary).

Comment: `colorOnePath.style.background[0]` ? you mean `colorOnePath[0].style.background` :p - personally I would add the `[0]` to all results of `getElementsBy*`

Comment: @JaromandaX -- good catch and good recommendation-- updated accordingly-- thanks!

Comment: another one `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]` === `document.body` :p

Comment: but `colorTwoPath` still have to be `colorTwoPath[0]` and `colorTwoPath[1]`

Comment: Oy, you'd think this weren't my day job :p  Fixed (again) -- thanks!

Comment: I'm a critic at heart :p

Comment: I'm adding a githook to send all my code to you for review before it gets committed :)